# Canonical-livepatch issue

Tags: canonical-livepatch

Need help in  enabiling livepatch:

Message: 2021/10/11 02:34:15 error executing config: Livepatchd error: Couldn't setup system logger: Unix syslog delivery error

Getting above error while enabling livepatch. Using syslog-ng for logging

Comment: Have you setup an account on the livepatch web site? https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch

Comment: yes, I have the account, It works for other  host

Comment: What version of Ubuntu you got?

Comment: @Jon using ubuntu 16

Comment: Ubuntu 16 is no longer supported. So livepatch might not work for that reason. Get the latest version of LTS that is 20.04 and you get livepatch again. Also you get security updates which is very important.

Comment: @jon, No it is working on other  ubuntu 16 boxes.

Comment: Oh ok I see. So livepatch is available for Ubuntu 16. It might be corrupted. Is it possible to reinstall livepatch?